# Dotnet Core Error handling in both web api and Mvc Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my web application, I have both web API and normal MVC in there
I have created an extension for httpResponse

```
 public static void ShowApplicationError(this HttpResponse response, string exceptionMessage,string innerException)
    {
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = exceptionMessage ,detail=innerException });
        response.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
```

and used in startup.cs for exception handling.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.ShowApplicationError(error.Error.Message, error.Error.InnerException.Message);
                    }
                });
            });
```

like this.
its works fine for both.
i want to differentiate the error for each request. i dont want to show the json error for mvc end how do i do that.

Comment: this must work for both... what is the problem? please define your problem

Comment: i want to know a request for mvc, so i can send the error differently. edited the post

Comment: AFAIK there's no inbuilt way to do this. Whether it's an API request or an MVC request, its the same internally. Try to separate the API to a specific area then you can use the `area` token to differentiate the requests and return the relevant type of response

Comment: Have you tried calling app.UseExceptionHandler before you call app.useMvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not distinguish the internal server error from MVC or web api from `Error.Message` directly. For `MVC` and `Web api`, they are both inherited from `Controller` or `ControllerBase`.

In general, we distinguish them by adding `api` to the route path for web api. I suggest you design your project by mvc without api route and web api with api route. Then check the path by `ExceptionHandlerFeature.Path`.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
{
    builder.Run(async context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var error1 = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>() as ExceptionHandlerFeature;
        var error2 = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        var requestPath = error2.Path;
        if (error != null)
        {
            context.Response.ShowApplicationError(error.Error.Message, error.Error.InnerException.Message);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So  I  have to make deferent projects for each

Comment: @Selik There is no need to split into two projects, you could define mvc controller and web api controller in the same project, just make sure add `[Route("api/[controller]")]` for every web api controller.

Comment: oh sorry, you were referring 'ExceptionHandlerFeature.Path' Yup its working.thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this situation is to separate your concerns better. Make your api a separate csproj from your MVC app. It will give you flexibility to deploy later on as well. If this is existing code and not new code, I would lobby for refactoring it into a separate api project.

Comment: That's obvious, but if he have that need, means than he want to make it in that way, maybe because is a test and he don't want to waste a lot of money or something for the school

Answer (score 0):

ContentType and Accept Header in HttpRequest differentiates output type which is enough in your case.

you can check by using Accept Header.

```
if (context.Request.Headers["Accept"] == "application/json" || context.Request.Headers["Accept"] == "application/xml")
{
    //Api Request
}
else
{
    //other request.
}
```